# I am trying to make an update engine with JS but I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, sirishortcuts

```js
let currentVersion ="CV";
let newVersion ="NV";

let currentVersionP = currentVersion.split('.');
let newVersionP = newVersion.split('.');

let i = 0;

if (isNaN(currentVersionP)) var _return = "0Masking";
else if (isNaN(newVersionP)) var _return = "0Masking";
if (newVersionP > currentVersionP) var _return = "UpdateAvailable";
if (newVersionP < currentVersionP) var _return = "RollbackAvailable";
if (newVersionP = currentVersionP) var _return = "NoChanges";
document.write(_return);
```

I Am trying to make an update engine for a Siri Shortcuts shortcut. But I don’t know what I am doing wrong. Someone please help me to change it that it work

Comment: What do you mean by `I am doing wrong` ? What is wrong ? what should it do ?

Comment: I mean like, it doesn’t work, the script. And in Siri Shortcuts there are updaters I am making one right now. I am making one with fully worded versions (e.g alpha and beta) and with multi decimals like 1.9 and 1.3. And I want a build-in function that it always detect if it is a rollback so 1.9 to 1.8 or an update 1.2 to the 1.3. For that you need a JavaScript code. I am making this one but it doesn’t work